# How to initialize a number from an array

Tags: java

I need to get a number from the array and initialize it to a variable so I can use it as an object. Im not sure if it would just be,

`int smallSpaces = 1;` for example.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

```
public class Port {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        String shipSize = null;
        String shipName = null;

        int smallSpaces = 1;
        int mediumSpaces = 2;
        int largeSpaces = 3;

        int[][] dockSpaces = {
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3},
        };

        int waitingList = 10;
        int menuChoice = 0;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("SHIP PORT APPLICATION");
            System.out.println("\n1. Add ship to port.");
            System.out.println("\n2. Remove ship from port.");
            System.out.println("\n3. View report.");
            System.out.println("\n4. Exit.");

            menuChoice = console.nextInt();

            switch (menuChoice) { // Using a switch case for the menu options
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Add ship to port");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Remove ship from port");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("View report");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Exit");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
            }

            try {
                FileWriter write = new FileWriter("PortLog.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(write);

                if (menuChoice == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Please select ship size(1. Cargo /n 2.Container /n 3. SuperContainer)");
                    shipSize = console.next();

                    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your ship");
                    shipName = console.next();

                    if (shipSize.equals("1")) {
                        smallSpaces++;
                        System.out.println("test");
                        write.write("SMALL"); // Printing line to output file about the transaction details
                        out.newLine();  //Adding new line to file writer
                        out.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'array and initialize it to a variable so I can use it as an object' -- how do you plan on using this? Only as a number?

Comment: I need to use the array to represent spaces, so when i get a user input to pick small/medium/large, it will assign it to the array so the space becomes unavailable and it will move onto the next space

Comment: i see. so the purpose of the array is to have your program keep track what sizes are at that particular array index? also do all small/medium/large take up the same number of slots? lastly is ur dockspaces constant 10x3?

Comment: Yes, its meant to be like a row of 3 docks, each having 10 spaces, 5 small 3 med and two large

Answer (score 0):

To initalize an int

```
int a = 1;
```

is enough. But while this is a variable it is not an Object it's a primitive type. Objects need to be created using keyword new while primitive types don't, in java primitive types are byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, char. String from initializing point of view is a special case, because it can be initialized with string literal.

Primitives:

```
int a = 1;
char c = 'c';
boolean b = true;
...
```

Objects:

```
Object a = new Object();
ClassA class = new ClassA();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use an object, primitive types in Java also have corresponding objects, like Integer, Double, etc.
For example:

```
Integer myInt = new Integer(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get a number from the array and initialize it to a variable so I can use it as an object. Im not sure if it would just be

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
int myVar = nums[0];   //will get first array element (initialize it to a variable)
```

If you want to use it **for an** object.

```
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
MyClass m = new MyClass(nums[0]);   //m's value (x) will be updated to num[0]

class MyClass
{
    int x;
    public MyClass(int x){  //Constructor
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

If you want to use it **as an** object.

```
//Use a wrapper class according to the array element's data type:
Integer val = new Integer(nums[0]);
```